# Dependency issue while using Flink to process twitter data

Tags: maven, twitter, apache-flink

I am trying to connect to twitter using Apache-Flink streaming using official documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/twitter.html) .

Although I am able to successfully parse the sample TwitterExampleData using the api , But when I am trying to connect the real data using the same I am getting ClassNotFoundException.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/twitter/shaded/com/google/common/base/Preconditions
at com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.BaseEndpoint.<init>(BaseEndpoint.java:37)
at com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.DefaultStreamingEndpoint.<init>(DefaultStreamingEndpoint.java:35)
at com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.StatusesSampleEndpoint.<init>(StatusesSampleEndpoint.java:24)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.twitter.TwitterSource$SampleStatusesEndpoint.createEndpoint(TwitterSource.java:208)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.twitter.TwitterSource.run(TwitterSource.java:124)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:87)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
```

From what I understand this was available at compile time and missing at Run time , how can I provide this to flink on run-time.

Below is the command that I am using:

```
./flink run /path/to/jar/target/Twitter.jar --output file:///tmp/b.out --twitter-source.consumerKey  <my-consumer-key> --twitter-source.consumerSecret <My consumer secret> --twitter-source.tokenSecret <my token secret> --twitter-source.token <my source token>
```

Note:

1. I am using the Fat jar , which was created using mvn clean package
2. My Access token are valid , I have verified the same as well

Comment: When you ran 'mvn clean package' you should've gotten 2 jars. 'flink-connector-twitter_2.11-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar'  and 'original-flink-connector-twitter_2.11-1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar'. Which one did you use?

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler : I am using Twitter.jar

Comment: ah, the one under /examples/streaming?

Comment: flink-examples-streaming_2.11-1.4-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar was getting renamed by build process

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler : Looks like i figured out the issue , thanks for your help. Needed to add <include>org/apache/flink/twitter/shaded/com/google/common/**</include> in the include list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stumbled upon a bug in the build process of the twitter example, causing a dependency from the source to be excluded. I've filed a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7761). In the meantime, to run the example you will have to build the twitter source manually (under flink/flink-connectors/flink-connectors-twitter) and copy the resulting jar into the /lib folder.

Until the fix arrives, add the below line in maven-shaded-plugin configuration of flink-examples-streaming.

```
<include>org/apache/flink/twitter/shaded/com/google/common/**</include>
```